# Why are Fourier series important?

Tags: calculus, education

Are there any real life applications of Fourier series?
Are there examples of Fourier series which have an impact on students learning this topic. I have found the normal suspects of examples in this field such as signal processing, electrical principles but there must be a vast range of applications as it is taught on most undergraduate courses in mathematics, physics and engineering. I am looking for examples which will motivate why students should study Fourier series.

Comment: For instance, just check its applications in cell phones?

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579453/what-are-some-real-world-application-of-fourier-series

Comment: It has great applications.
Check out this link. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579453/real-world-application-of-fourier-series

Answer (score 3):

It was originally used by Fourier to solve the heat equation, thus calculating the temperature field.

It is also a nice example of a base change of a function space (Taylor expansion vs Fourier expansion).

Maybe the JPEG compression by DCT is a nice example (Cell phone! Cell phone! :-)

BTW this is my favourite animation regarding Fourier series

http://bl.ocks.org/jinroh/7524988